# Not working variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery for getting data from XML file, but it doesn't work, it writes only:

> [object Object]

And I have no idea what to do with it...
Here's the code in javascript file:

```
function produkty() {
var lowermenu = document.getElementById("lower2");
if  (lowermenu.innerHTML==="")  {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "menu.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
    });
});
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("#products").each(function()
  {
      var link = $(this).attr('link_url'); 
      var child = $(this).find("under_subitem").each(function() {
        "<ul class='droplist'><li><a href='"+$(this).attr('link_url')+"'>"+$(this).attr('name')+"</a></li></ul>"
})
        switch($(this).attr('active')){
          case 'on':
            $("#lower2").append("<li id='"+$(this).attr('name')+"'><p class='menulink'>"+$(this).attr('name')+"</p>"+child+"</li>");
            break;
        case 'off':
            $("#lower2").append("<li><p class='menulink'><a href='"+link+"' class='inactive'>"+$(this).attr('name')+"</p></li>");
            break;
        case 'invisible':
            $("#lower2").append("<li style='display: none;'><p   class='menulink'><a href='"+link+"'>"+$(this).attr('name')+"</p></li>");
            break;
                }
            });
         }

  }else {
    lowermenu.innerHTML = "";
}
}
```

Here is HTML code(the important part of it):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul class="mmenu">
<?php
$menu=simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
foreach($menu->item as $HTMLTAG){
        $inactiveHTML = " class='inactive'>";
        $end = "</a></p></li>";
        $activeHTML = ">";
        $url = $HTMLTAG['link_url'];
        $sname = $HTMLTAG['sname'];
    switch($url){
        case "":
            $mainHTML = "<li onclick='$sname()'><p class='menulink'>";
            $end = "</p></li>";
            break;
        default:
            $mainHTML = "<li><p class='menulink'><a href = '$url'>";
            $end = "</a></p></li>";
            break;}
            $invisibleHTML = "<li style='display: none;'><p class='menulink'><a href='$url'";
        switch($HTMLTAG['active']){
            case "on":
                echo $mainHTML.$HTMLTAG.$end;
                break;
            case "off":
                $mainHTML = "<li><p class='menulink'><a href = '$url'";
                echo $mainHTML.$inactiveHTML.$HTMLTAG.$end;
                break;
            case "invisible":
                echo $invisibleHTML.$activeHTML.$HTMLTAG.$end;
                break;
        }
    }
?>
<script src="/scripts/menulower2.js" language="javascript"></script>
</ul>
<br />
<div class="overline">
<ul id="lower2"></ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is important part of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu_items>
    <item link_url='' active="on" sname="onas">O nás
        <subitem link_url='/about' active="on" id="about" name="O nás"></subitem>
        <subitem link_url='/about/reference' active="on" id="about" name="Reference"></subitem>
        <subitem link_url='/about/contact' active="on" id="about" name="kontakty"></subitem>
    </item>
    <item link_url='' active="on" sname="produkty">Produkty
        <subitem link_url='/HeatMatrix' active="on" id="products" name="HeatMatrix">
            <under_subitem link_url='/HeatMatrix/LUVO' id="HeatMatrix" name="Předehřívač vzduchu LUVO"></under_subitem>
            <under_subitem link_url='/HeatMatrix/HV' id="HeatMatrix" name="Hybridní výměníky"></under_subitem>
            <under_subitem link_url='/HeatMatrix/KP' id="HeatMatrix" name="Výměníky kapalina-plyn"></under_subitem>
            <under_subitem link_url='/HeatMatrix/VCS' id="HeatMatrix" name="Vestavěný čistící systém"></under_subitem></subitem>
        <subitem link_url='/OCR' active="off" id="products" name="OCR systémy"></subitem>
        <subitem link_url='/LDR' active="off" id="products" name="Točivé redukce"></subitem>
    </item>
    </menu_items>
```

I have no idea what to do with it... Can anyone help me?
Anyway... In CSS it's it's made as droplist menu - that is why there is so much of list tags...

Comment: var child = $(this).find("under_subitem") .... inside of this function you're creating a string but doing nothing with it.

Comment: If you look at it again, you'll see that the function is definition of variable "child" that I use in the switch, cause as you can see in the XML code there is more of children an I need all of them to have the same stylization, what I'm doing with the string in the middle of the function... In short: I want the var Child to be array made of string with loaded XML attributes.

Comment: It seems there's a fundamental misunderstanding of how jQuery works here. You can't convert a jQuery object directly to a string. It has methods .html() and .text() for that. Also, the contents of the .each() function is still doing nothing. You should probably be assigning that string to a variable.

Comment: Actually, I wrote here because I am a beginner to webpage designing and learning by myself like this is the best way how to learn it, but sometime I don't simply understand what I'm doing like this time and I need an example what is wrong and how to fix it... So you are saying that I should do something like this:

Comment: var bchild = $(this).find("under_subitem"); var bechild = bchild.html(); var child = [...dat...string...with...bechild...variable...]??

Comment: I created an answer with what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable to contain the generated HTML string of your list items and append to that variable inside the `.each()` loop.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("#products").each(function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('link_url');
        // BEGIN CHANGE
        // Concatinate all of the under_subitem HTML into a single variable.
        var child = ''; 
        $(this).find("under_subitem").each(function() {
            child += "<ul class='droplist'><li><a href='" + $(this).attr('link_url') + "'>" + $(this).attr('name') + "</a></li></ul>";
        });
        // END CHANGE
        switch ($(this).attr('active')) {
            case 'on':
                $("#lower2").append("<li id='" + $(this).attr('name') + "'><p class='menulink'>" + $(this).attr('name') + "</p>" + child + "</li>");
                break;
            case 'off':
                $("#lower2").append("<li><p class='menulink'><a href='" + link + "' class='inactive'>" + $(this).attr('name') + "</p></li>");
                break;
            case 'invisible':
                $("#lower2").append("<li style='display: none;'><p   class='menulink'><a href='" + link + "'>" + $(this).attr('name') + "</p></li>");
                break;
        }
    });
}
```